# ImportError: cannot import name 'timezone' while importing NLTK

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

While importing NLTK in Python2 or Python3, the error shows up that 'timezone' cannot be imported while importing NLTK. It worked fine few days earlier.
Someone please help. The output is below.

For Python3

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Nov 17 2016, 01:08:31) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
........
........
from datetime import timezone
ImportError: cannot import name 'timezone'
```

For Python2

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
from nltk.internals import config_java
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 31, in <module>
from nltk import compat
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/compat.py", line 45, in <module>
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta
ImportError: cannot import name tzinfo
```

Comment: pip install timezone

Comment: Note it might be pip3. Check that as pip might be associated with Python2.7 if you have it.

Comment: yeah i used pip3 for python3

Comment: Which version of `nltk` are you using? `python -c "import nltk; print(nltk.__version__)`

Comment: the above also gives the same error - `from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta
 ImportError: cannot import name tzinfo`

Answer (score 2):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **UPDATE (Problem Solved)**
>   The issue has been solved now - turns out the problem was that i had a folder named datetime in my current working directory which was actually being imported by the file since the first element of the searched path is The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified).
>   In short, Just renaming that folder solved all the problems. Thanks anyway to all.

Comment: It hasn't been mistaken for the library: it's how the python import system work, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path). The first element of the searched path is ``The directory containing the input script (or the current directory when no file is specified)``

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install `dateutil` package of python.
dateutil provides datetime parsing and timezone conversion.
Then try importing nltk